# VSCode extension Intelephense gives error "Undefined method 'xxx'. Intelephense (1013)" with polymorphism and dynamic binding

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, intelephense

I'm developing a PHP (v7.0.33) project using VScode (v1.56). I recently installed the VSCode's extension Intelephense (v1.7.1) and started to clean my code following Intelephense suggestions.

A set of classes inside my project has the following structure (function names are not real, but just to let you see that for each sublcass I have some function overrided from the superclass (those with the prefix `baseFunction`) and new functions specific for that subclass (those with the class acronym like `fdmSpecificFunction`):

[image]

According to the diagram, each DocumentSaver has an instance of a DocumentManager.
The code where I create an instance of, for example, `FatturaVenditaDocumentSaver` is

```php
$documentManager = new FatturaVenditaDocumentManager();
$documentSaver = new FatturaVenditaDocumentSaver($documentManager);
$documentSaver->baseFunction1();
```

Consider the following code inside `FatturaVenditaDocumentSaver`:

```php
public function baseFunction1() {
    parent::baseFunction1();
    $this->documentManager->fvdmSpecificFunction1();
}
```

This is a common implementation in OOP, using polymorphism and dynamic binding: having created the instance of `FatturaVenditaDocumentSaver` with a document manager instantiated from `FatturaVenditaDocumentManager`, the call `$documentSaver->baseFunction1()` will execute the code implemented in `FatturaVenditaDocumentSaver` and, inside it, will correctly execute the code inside `fvdmSpecificFunction1()` implemented in `FatturaVenditaDocumentManager`.

The problem is that Intelephense, as `fvdmSpecificFunction` is not defined in `BaseDocumentManager`, gives me the error "Undefined method 'fvdmSpecificFunction1'. Intelephense (1013)".

Is there a way to let Intelephense understand the real implementation of my code (considering that Intelephense parse all my PHP code)? I'd like to avoid to disable the Intelliphense's "undefined method" check and I don't like to add an empty `fvdmSpecificFunction1` in `BaseDocumentManager` as is not consistent with the project's logic.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found!

I had just to add the `@property` hint before the `class` block, specifying the type of the object `$documentManager`.

```php
/**
 * @property    FatturaVenditaDocumentManager   $documentManager
 */
class FatturaVenditaSaver extends FatturaSaver {
    public function baseFunction1() {
        parent::baseFunction1();
        $this->documentManager->fvdmSpecificFunction1();
    }
}
```

In this way, Intelephense understands the real class related to that object.

Comment: This seems nice. Although I have a similar, but different problem. I need to do this for an argument. There's a dynamically added property on the received argument (object) in some function. Is there a way to solve this with a doc comment? Otherwise I'll have to define the property on the class (even if it's dynamically populated [ORM thing]).

Comment: @akinuri, If all the possible classes of the argument inherit from the same interface, you could specify the interface in the `@param` definition in doc block.